# Algorithmically decide if an algorithm has optimal time complexity

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity, computability-theory, computer-science

Is there an algorithm with the following input and output?

INPUT: an algorithm computing a function $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$. The algorithm is guaranteed to halt on all inputs.

OUTPUT: "YES" if there is another algorithm computing the same function with lower asymptotic time complexity and "NO" otherwise.

Comment: Let us suppose that there is an algorithm $T$ computing a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, such that no algorithm computes it with lower asymptotic complexity. (If such $T$ doesn't exist, the constant YES algorithm works.) Now make an algorithm $T''$ that computes $f$ using the optimal algorithm $T$ and runs another algorithm $T'$ in parallel (which doesn't change asymptotics). If $T'$ halts, $T''$ starts taking more time on inputs after that, but still computes $f$. This proves undecidability. This is a bit off-topic, essentially this is some variant of Rice's theorem.

Comment: I suppose an optimal $T$ exists no matter what your computational model is, take $f(n) = 0$ and $T$ outputs $0$ without inspecting the input.

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for such questions.

Comment: @VilleSalo Perhaps consider making your comment into an answer, for the benefit of future readers? (If you don't feel it "deserves points" then you can always ask the mods to make the answer community wiki)

Comment: I didn't answer because I figured it'll be closed (/ moved) and because a good answer should explain the Rice theorem deduction. I certainly feel I deserve many points, so that's not it. I can make an answer, but not right now.

Comment: I don't think this is research level - its rather straight-forward with the background of an introduction to computability theory course.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: I think this type of question makes more sense here than on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ since the latter is about research level computer science. No computer science researcher would ask such a question, a mathematician might. I don't know what the correct choice is, I voted to close and move to math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @YemonChoi, no need to ask mods for CW on answers; the user can make it so themselves.  (It's questions that require mod intervention for CW.)

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev The appropriate site for this type of questions is neither here nor cstheory, but https://cs.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 3):

Philosophically this is solved by Rice's theorem: No non-trivial semantic property of a Turing machine can be determined algorithmically. Optimal running time is not a property that the theorem literally covers, but the same proof works here.

Here is the proof: Let us suppose that there is an algorithm $T$ computing a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, such that no algorithm computes it with lower asymptotic complexity. (If such T doesn't exist, the constant YES algorithm works.) Now make an algorithm $T''$ that computes $f$ using the optimal algorithm $T$ and runs another algorithm $T'$ in parallel (which doesn't change asymptotics). If $T'$ halts, $T''$ starts taking more time on inputs after that, but still computes $f$. This proves undecidability.

With any natural computational model, you can take $f(n) = 0$ and an $O(1)$ algorithm that does not inspect the input.

Comment: I don't get this argument. So your algorithm $T''$ takes as input an integer and outputs an integer. A compiler (which is a program) should be able to recognize that $T''$ has some "submodules" that don't refer to the global variables and that are never invoked in the "main body" of the program (the one that actually outputs an integer). Thus we can computably recognize this Trojan horse and refuse check its complexity (since it cannot have better asymptotics than $T$). I think you need to intertwine the two algorithms more closely so that a compiler couldn't tell they are independent.

Comment: Faris: You are correct that if you have a computational model that "forbids useless subroutines", then my solution is not sufficient, and maybe it is not a crazy definition of an algorithm. I imagine you can diagonalize against any optimization principle somehow, I will give it some thought.